# Retrieving Data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I setup my database and want to display first name last name email and age. It is only displaying the first name. here is my code:

```
<?php
$host_name = 'localhost';
$db_user ='root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'mydb';
/* Connect to MySQL */
 $con = mysql_connect("$host_name","$db_user","$db_pass") or die ("Couldn't connect!");
 $db = mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Couldn't connect to database!");

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");


/*Fetch the results / convert into an array */
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
        $rows = $rows['first_name'];
        $last_name = $rows['last_name'];


                echo
             $rows.'</br>'.$last_name;
            }
?>
```

This is error i get

Warning: Illegal string offset 'last_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 17
eric
e
Warning: Illegal string offset 'last_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 17
stacey
s

I checked my tables and all fields exist what is wrong with my coding so far. I didnt add the email or age because i will still get offstring error.

Comment: How about assign `$rows['first_name'];` to a variable name other than `$rows`?

Comment: show your table columns please ?

Comment: $rows = $rows['first_name']; This line is your problem. When you try to get last name you are no longer accessing array, but string variable.

Comment: note: mysql will be deprecated use mysqli instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
        $first_name = $rows['first_name']; 
        $last_name = $rows['last_name'];



             echo $first_name .'</br>'.$last_name;
            }
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving same name `$rows` to first name and to the fetch

try change the name

```
   $rows = $rows['first_name'];
```

to

```
   $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
```

then

```
 echo $first_name.'</br>'.$last_name;
```

Comment: Ok i got it thanks for help everyone i changed it from $rows = $rows to firstname age and so on. When i did that at first it still didnt work because thats what i originally did but I must have had something  wrong in the coding. My other question is im trying to make a login script that displays an error message on the same page. For example when someone tries to login it will say please enter username and or password

Comment: this maybe javascript will help you to detect if inputs are empty . if you want do it by page submit then its php

Comment: i apologize im new to javascript . How would i need to setup my code along with javascript to apply my error messages.